# PHP replacing parenthesis and numbers

Tags: php, replace, web-scraping

I've created a code to scrap some data from website and now I only wants the data without the parenthesis and numbers.

This is my code but this can only replace integers but not parentheses.

```
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
$span = $node->childNodes;
$categories = preg_replace("/[0-9]/", '', $span->item(0)->nodeValue);
echo '<br>' . '<font color="green">' . $categories . ' : ' . '</font>' ;
```

How do I replace parenthesis too? Tq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add parenthesis to your preg_replace pattern.

```
$categories = preg_replace("/[0-9()]/", '', $span->item(0)->nodeValue);
```

Or, use str_replace instead of preg_replace for faster, more efficient code.

```
$search = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'(',')');
$categories = str_replace($search, '', $span->item(0)->nodeValue);
```